# Laravel 5 - Cache remember doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, internal-server-error

I have tried to cache some queries with Cache::remember(); but it doesn't work.

My script response code is 500(Internal Server Error).

Here is my code:

```
 $filters = \Cache::remember("cache_filter", 20, function(){
      $data['value1'] = MyClass::where('<condition>')->get();
      $data['value2'] = MyClass::where('<condition>')->get();
      $data['value3'] = MyClass::where('<condition>')->get();

      return $data;
 });     
 return view('custom.show')->with($filters);
```

`Storage` permissions => `777` 
`Cache path`          => `storage_path('framework/cache')`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: make value of debug parameter in app.php true to get more information about error.

Comment: still the same - no errors previewed.

Comment: @HerilMuratovic You are not seeing a stack trace?

Comment: no. there is no errors.

Comment: on the first call it shows me the data but every next call is internal server error with no errors previewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `php artisan cache:clear`
2. if you have run `php artisan config:cache` before then you have to delete `config.php` file from `bootstrap/cache/`, if not then just run first command **(1.)**
3. Try to run your code for caching data.