# Cannot write Cache to Database Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to send some cache to the database. But when I run the cache function there isn't a row in the database
`Cache::forever('key', 'data');`

If I had a `dd` to it, it returns `null`.

Things I did

- Making a migration file

  `Schema::create('cache', function (Blueprint $table) {
              $table->string('key')->unique();
              $table->mediumText('value');
              $table->integer('expiration');`

  - Including the `use Cache;` Class
  - Changed `'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'database'),` in `config/cache.php`
  - Also in .env file `CACHE_DRIVER=database`

Did I miss something :) (Thank you)

Comment: Is your error log outputting anything?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but no it only returns `NULL`

Comment: I am sure you did this, but I will ask anyway, did you run migration?

Comment: Yes, I did. The table exists

Comment: When you indicated cache driver as database, then below in the array of stores, did you indicate which database connection to use?

Comment: @NickSurmanidze I have only this `    'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
        ],`

Comment: I think you need to replace "null" with "mysql" or whichever database you are using

Comment: I have tried that, but it still returns `null` and won't add something to the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184270/discussion-between-nick-surmanidze-and-daansk44).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that deleting my `config.php` file in `bootstrap/cache/` seems to work.
I re-run the command

[Laravel 5 - Cache remember doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937153/laravel-5-cache-remember-doesnt-work)

Thanks you all